# What is the minimum code to access Laravel's services without using HTTP/Console Kernels?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to access to my app services in a simple php script. I don't want to create a  HTTP/Console kernel. If the following is the content `test.php` file in the app root, what else should I call to make it working?

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php"; //composer
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(realpath(__DIR__));
$app->boot(); // not sure about this
$app->make('db')->table('user')->get()->toArray();
```

Currently I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class db does not exist in foo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:752
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class db does not exist in foo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:752
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the right thing for your? Did you tried Silex? Can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: @SebTM oh! I asked one question and you asked  three questions! So funny!

Comment: Just create an artisan command, that's what it is made for.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the source code it's clear that the Application class does not load all classes defined in the `config/app.php` file and either you have bootstrap it yourself of running bootstrap function of build-in kernel. So, If you create a php file with the following lines you can access all app dependencies without bothering creating artisan command to do your snippet codes directly in phpstorm.

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php"; //composer
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(realpath(__DIR__));

// http Kernel yet have to be registered, perhaps a bad design issue.
$app->singleton(
  Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
  App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
  Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
  App\Console\Kernel::class
);
// optional
$app->singleton(
  Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
  App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
$kernel->bootstrap();

// and playground is ready 
$users= $app->make('db')->table('user')->get()->toArray();
```

**or**

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
$app = include_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
$kernel->bootstrap();

dd(app('db')->table('user')->count());
```